# Blaze-html class attribute chaining / appending / concatenation?

Tags: html, haskell, blaze-html

I've been working on some quickly-growing Haskell based web applications, and am finding myself shot in the foot with this issue. Suppose I have some template that I've defined early in my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Text.Blaze.Html5
import Text.Blaze.Html5.Attributes
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5 as H
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5.Attributes as A

foo = H.div ! class_ "foo"
```

and later, I decide to use `foo`, but with a slight *non-destructive* amendment:

```
bar = foo ! class_ "bar" -- this should add bar to the classes available, imo
```

but alas, when I render the html, here is the result I get:

```
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.String

λ: renderHtml $ bar "baz"


↪ "<div class=\"foo\" class=\"bar\"></div>"
```

This is a *monad*, after all! Is there any way we could integrate this kind of logic into blaze-html? Or is that beyond the scope of the templating framework? Are there any methods of selection (like jQuery), such that I could do something along the lines of...

```
bar' = do
  classes <- classesOf foo
  H.div ! class_ (classes ++ " bar")
```

Has anyone found a way around this? Are there any type-assisted Html tools for Haskell out there? This really has me scratching my head, and coming up with horrible ideas...

Comment: `MarkupM` doesn't satisfy the monad laws: `anything >>= return = Empty`, so it's not really a monad.

Comment: I had no idea. Looks like we'll be getting some html tools with lens-style subtype coercion and attribute inclusion safety. :)

(okay maybe not ALL OF lens. :x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The current version of blaze doesn't support monoidal attribute manipulation.

## Technical details

### Problem

An [`Attribute`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-markup-0.6.1.0/docs/src/Text-Blaze-Internal.html#Attribute) is a newtype wrapper:

```
newtype Attribute = Attribute (forall a. MarkupM a -> MarkupM a)
```

Most (X)HTML attributes are created with `Text.Blaze.Internal.attribute`:

```
attribute :: Tag             -- ^ Raw key
      -> Tag             -- ^ Shared key string for the HTML attribute.
      -> AttributeValue  -- ^ Value for the HTML attribute.
      -> Attribute       -- ^ Resulting HTML attribute.
attribute rawKey key value = Attribute $
    AddAttribute (unTag rawKey) (unTag key) (unAttributeValue value)
```

where `AddAttribute` is one of [`MarkupM`'s](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-markup-0.6.1.0/docs/src/Text-Blaze-Internal.html#MarkupM) constructors:

```
data MarkupM a
    = {- ... -}
    -- | Add an attribute to the inner HTML. Raw key, key, value, HTML to
    -- receive the attribute.
    | AddAttribute StaticString StaticString ChoiceString (MarkupM a)
      {- ... -}
```

Now, `(!)` from [`Attributable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-markup-0.6.1.0/docs/src/Text-Blaze-Internal.html#Attributable) will basically apply the `Attribute`. So given an attribute `foo`, and an attribute `bar`, `tag ! bar ! foo` is the same as `foo $ bar $ tag`. The renderer later unwraps the `AddAttribute` constructors:

```
go attrs (AddAttribute _ key value h) =
    go (B.copyByteString (getUtf8ByteString key)
        `mappend` fromChoiceString value
        `mappend` B.fromChar '"'
        `mappend` attrs) h
```

### A solution

In order to achieve your desired behaviour, you need to defer the attribute rendering a little bit further and collect the attributes in a intermediate data structure, for example a `Map ChoiceString AttributeValue`.

However, keep in mind that all the types in this post are in `Text.Blaze.Internal` if you want to create your own renderer.

## Answers

> This is a monad, after all!

No, it's not, it doesn't follow the monad laws.

> Is there any way we could integrate this kind of logic into blaze-html?

See above, but keep in mind that the internal API can change.

> Or is that beyond the scope of the templating framework?

Apparently, it's at least beyond the scope of blaze. Also, I don't whether an additional `Map` will introduce performance issues, which could undo the "blazingly fast" part of blaze.

> Are there any methods of selection (like jQuery), such that I could do something along the lines of...

See above, `MarkupM` isn't a real monad. You *could* unravel the constructors to get to the correct `AddAttributes`, but again, that's an internal type and constructor.